# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for mysql://127.11.114.2:3306/donateblood

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc

In a Java web application, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for mysql://127.11.114.2:3306/donateblood
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 47 more
```

I have changed the drivers but still the error remains. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: is driver in your classpath?

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: Where did you got that MySQL JDBC URL syntax from? I'm not seeing that anywhere in [MySQL JDBC documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

Comment: Shouldn't it be jdbc:mysql://127.11.114.2:3306/donateblood?